# Embed a specific layer into a Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, embed

The embed code for my Google Map is:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zntuAGg8LK44.k9Si-_ekqYvk" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

This gives a map that has 6 layers, I'm working on making a Javascript/jQuery map system that changes the layer when clicked. Or just having a seperate map for each layer. The thing is, when you start, it has no layers selected.

Is there any way to get a specific layer. E.g:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=mapsID&layer=1
```

So that it starts with that layer (whether it's directions, location pins, or whatever.

Thanks if I can get any help, and thanks even if not :)
-PXgamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may give you an idea:

```
var layers = { directionslayer:null, locationpinslayer:null, whateverlayer:null };

// Create your layers (layers.directionslayer = etc.)

// e.g. https://mywebsite.com/map#directionslayer
var currentLayer = window.location.hash.slice(1).toLowerCase();

if (layers[currentLayer])
    setLayer(layers[currentLayer]);
else
    setLayer(layers.directionslayer);

function setLayer(layer){
    for (prop in layers)
        layers[prop].setMap(null);
    layer.setMap(map);
}
```